# Present list of items in tableview from Realm database

Tags: ios, swift, list, uitableview, realm

I am successfully downloading and printing data from Realm database. Here is my log:

```
Item(id: Optional(0), name: Optional("Item (0)"), descr: Optional("Description of item (0)"),
     icon: Optional("http://192.168.1.101:8080/api/items/0/icon.png"),
     url: Optional("http://192.168.1.101:8080/api/items/0")))
```

Now I have to assign those values on actual list and I am getting a clean sheet tableview. How to do it properly? I am using .xib as tablewViewCell. I am thankful for any tips.

```
class ItemRealm : Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var desc = ""
    dynamic var icon = ""


    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,    UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    let realm = try! Realm()
    let results = try! Realm().objects(ItemRealm.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "id")

    let SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.1.101:8080/api/items"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(SERVER_URL).responseJSON { response in
            let items = [Item].from(jsonArray: response.result.value as! [Gloss.JSON])
            print(items?[0] as Any)

            try! self.realm.write {
                for item in items! {
                    let itemRealm = ItemRealm()
                    itemRealm.id = item.id!
                    itemRealm.name = item.name!
                    itemRealm.desc = item.descr!
                    itemRealm.icon = item.icon!
                    self.realm.add(itemRealm)
                }
            }
            _ = self.realm.objects(ItemRealm.self)
           // print(items?[0] as Any)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    }

    // MARK: - UITableView data source
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return results.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

        var object: ItemRealm
        object = self.results[indexPath.row] as ItemRealm

        cell.item = object

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: have you linked the tableView delegates?  Is results.count definitely > 0, and is `cellForRowAt` ever called?

Comment: Yes, they are linked. After debugging -> po results.count - it gives me 0..cellForRow is not even called.

Comment: if result.count == 0, the `cellForRowAt` will never be called - means the problem is not the tableView, but the data retrieval.

Comment: Okey. Thanks. Any suggestions what to do with that?

Comment: i still not understand: you have 2 databases? `Server A = 192.168.1.101:8080` and `Server R = Realm` then you request items from Server A and move the items to a Server R Realm database? then you retrieve this new items again from the Server R Realm database?

Comment: Well yes, this is kind of recruitment test so I have to download data from server A and save it to local database Realm and then show this on the list from Realm. Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing `self.tableView.reloadData()` after getting data from the response. Consider also assigning fetched data to your results variable.

Comment: This is not helping unfortunately. What do you mean with fetched data, Can u give an example?

Comment: Change 'results' to variable and change this line: '_ = self.realm.objects(ItemRealm.self)' to 'self.results = self.realm.objects(ItemRealm.self)' after that call 'self.tableView.reloadData()'